# RS232 to ttl communication of arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, communication

I have an rs232 to TTL converter and I want to read something in the Arduino serial monitor by using the converter instead of using Arduino serial cable. I have connected the correct wiring in my opinion such as tx, Rx, Vcc and GND of the converter to Arduino pin 0 (Rx), pin 1 (Tx), 3.3 V and GND. But when I write something in the serial monitor of Arduino, I am getting nothing. But when I use only the arduino serial cable then I receive what I am writing in the serial monitor. Kindly can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you wire RX to TX?

Comment: The Uno works on 5V. Is your TTL converter 5V tolerant? Or why did you wire 3.3V?

Comment: Have you disconnected the Arduino's built-in serial connection to the USB interface?